# Python 3.9.6 screen wont show colours

Tags: pygame

I am making a type racer game using pygame and I'm a beginner. I've just started and I am already running into problems.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()


def display():
    # setting up the screen size, colours and other necessities
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((92, 100, 150))

    # Customizing and personalizing my screen
    pygame.display.set_caption("Typing Racer!")
    icon = pygame.image.load("exercise (1).png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)





running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            running = False


    display()

pygame.display.update()
```

When I run this code, it does not seem to take into consideration the screen.fill and instead just shows a black screen. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

`pygame.display.update()` needs to be indented because it needs to run every frame. You also don't want to create the window every frame, so it should be outside the display function.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# setting up the screen size, colours and other necessities
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 800))
    
def display():
    # RGB - Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((92, 100, 150))

    # Customizing and personalizing my screen
    pygame.display.set_caption("Typing Racer!")
    icon = pygame.image.load("exercise (1).png")
    pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    display()

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```